# Using Python variables within sqlite3 statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to use python variable within a sql request.

```
ss_length = 15
```

I tried this :

```
cursor = db.execute("SELECT SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, %s), count(SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, %s)) FROM tweets GROUP BY SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, %s) ORDER BY count(SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, %s))" % ss_length, ss_length, ss_length, ss_length)
```

and this

```
cursor = db.execute("SELECT SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?), count(SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?)) FROM tweets GROUP BY SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?) ORDER BY count(SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?))", ss_length, ss_length, ss_length, ss_length)
```

No one of the two worked for me.

What's wrong with them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this and it worked, thank you all for your responses:

```
cursor = db.execute("""SELECT SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?), count(SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?)) 
                       FROM tweets 
                       GROUP BY SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?) 
                       ORDER BY count(SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, ?))
                    """, (ss_length, ss_length, ss_length, ss_length))
```

Comment: I am not sure why I am obliged to add the last "," after ss_length. Without it, the query don't work.

Comment: Yes, it worked without the last comma, but first time I removed it it haven't worked for me.. weird. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: In my experience, embedded SQL queries are much easier to manage when split across multiple lines. I took the liberty of reformatting the example, which I think makes it easier to understand.